# Pass variables to my jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have build some jquery plugin to learn about it.
It works so far but I have build up my plugin around some test dates and now I try to open my plugin with the dates from outside.

here my work:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a0gvg89y/)

And I want to call my plugin with passing the days like:

```
var days = [
    new Event('9-3','test1'),
    new Event('9-5', 'test2'),
    new Event('9-7', 'test3')
];
$("#cal").calendar({ 
    year: "2015", 
    month: "9", 
    events: days 
});
```

How I do that!? thanks for helping me out...

Comment: Is what possible? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Call the plugin from outside?

Comment: Are you trying to make use of the option `events` in your plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lqratxp1/

You can now create an object containing the data for the events you want to create.
You can now initialize it in this way:

```
$("#cal").calendar( {year:"2015" month:"9",events:{'9-3':'test1','9-4':'test2'}});
```

All you had to do was to change the calendar class:

```
var days = [];

$.each(config.events,function(k,v){
   days.push(new Event(k,v))
});
```

That's used to convert the object you passed as parameter in an array of events.

Here the full class:

```
jQuery.fn.calendar = function(settings){

    var config = {
    // default settings
        year: "",
        month: "",
        events:  []
    // ...
    };
    // change default settings
    if (settings) { config = $.extend( {}, config, settings ); }

    var dayIndex = 0;

    function Event(start,title){        

        var parts = start.split('-');
        this.start= new Date(parts[2] || new Date().getFullYear(), parts[0] - 1, parts[1]);
        this.end= new Date(this.start);         

        this.title = title;
    }

    var days = [];

    $.each(config.events,function(k,v){
        days.push(new Event(k,v))
    });


    var mon = config.month - 1; // (1)
    var d = new Date(config.year, mon, 1);
    var start = 2 - d.getDay();
    var dateobj = new Date();
    var table = ['<table>'];

    while (d.getMonth() <= mon) {
        table.push('<tr>');

        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            d = new Date(config.year, mon, start++);
            tmp = '<td>';
            tmp += '<div class="date">' + d.getDate() + '</div><div class="titlecontainer">';               

            var events = days.filter(function(e){ return e.start <= d && e.end >= d;}); //get all events for this day               
            if(events.length){          
                events.forEach(function(e){
                    tmp += '<div class="title">'
                        + e.title //+ ' grid:' + e.grid
                        + '</div>';
                });
            }
            tmp += '</div></td>';
            table.push(tmp)
        }
        table.push('</tr>');
    }
    table.push('</table>')
    $( this ).html(table.join('\n'));
};


$("#cal").calendar( { year: "2015", month: "9",events:{'9-3':'test1','9-4':'test2'} } );
```

Answer (score 0):

And, yes this is possible, with just a feel adjustments.

I've edited your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/a0gvg89y/1/).

```
var days = [
    new Event('9-3','test11'),
    new Event('9-5', 'test22'),
    new Event('9-7', 'test33')
];

$("#cal").calendar( { year: "2015", month: "9", events: days } );
```

First point is that the Event class should be visible outside of plugin context, in this case was inside the plugin contex you couldn't see them for instantiate outside of plugin.

For make things more easy for a plugin you may consider using object literals insted of a class to create the Event object.